# How to set Proxy Address using QProcessEnvironment on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

I am stuck with a simple issue in Qt. I want set proxy address using Qt. The command to set proxy address

```
 export http_proxy=http://wwgw.abcd.com:8080
```

works fine if passed by a terminal manually. but If the same command is run using QProcess, it fails without setting proxy. Even, I tried with QProcessEnvironment as

```
QProcess process_setupProxyServerUrl;
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();

QString cmd = "http://wwgw.abcd.com:8080";

env.insert("HTTP_PROXY", cmd);
process_setupProxyServerUrl.setProcessEnvironment(env);
```

But this also fails in setting up proxy address. QProcessEnvironment is new for me. So may be i might be using it in wrong way.

In my application, I need to change the proxy address according to users choice (at run time).

Any way using Qt would be helpfull. Please provide some suggestions/ideas to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like that

```
QProcess process_setupProxyServerUrl;
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
env.insert("HTTP_PROXY", "http://wwgw.abcd.com:8080");
process_setupProxyServerUrl.setProcessEnvironment(env);
```

Why did you use export ? This is just an executable, not the environment key

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried with this. But i again no success in setting Proxy.