# How to execute "export" command in linux via Qt

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qprocess

As per my question, I am unable to execute "export" command in linux via Qt.

I tried QProcess, but it didn't worked.

Actually I need to set Proxy Address in Linux OS.
The command to set proxy address is:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://proxy-server.mycorp.com:3128/
```

I want to execute this command via Qt. I tried using QProcess, but it didn't worked.

I also tried QProcessEnvironment as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950755/how-to-set-proxy-address-using-qprocessenvironment-on-linux).

Can any one suggest me better way to executed this command ??

Also is there other way to set Proxy Server on Linux via Qt ??

Any idea/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

I am using Qt 4.7.4 (Cannot switch to higher version as per company policy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

export isn't eucutable file, Qt process uses exec C function , So you can't do it, you can run `ls -l`, but export , set ,you can't run `bash built-in` commands. you should direct uses C function for `environ-variable`. if you read `man  getenv` you can solve your problem.

For your case, you can do via `setenv C function`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried using setenv("http_proxy", "http://proxy-server.mycorp.com:3128/", 1). It return '0'. Also I used getenv(), it displayed the same proxy server. But When i am trying to check it on terminal using command "printenv" or "echo $http_proxy" nothing is shown on the terminal. Can you help me with more information on the same.

Comment: Be sure, it's normal, if you cat `/proc/[PID]/envorin` file, you'll find out every program has itself environment variable, So when you exit from a program you don't access to thsose. by the way , don't forget to acceppt my anwer.

Comment: I tested the function again in Qt. It is setting the Proxy Address Application-wide and system-wide. means when application is closed, the proxy-address is gone. And when Application is started, we need to set the proxy server again. Can you help me setting proxy server system-wide ?

Comment: Oh, your solution is wrong,you should  socket connection to your proxey server.

Comment: can you provide me more info on socket connection ? link would be better. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above; `export` is not an executable file, it is a **built-in** *bash* command. The `exec` variant functions by their nature, replace the current process image with a new process image. Therefore, you can only use `exec` variants on executable programs or processes. In **Unix/Linux** operating systems, every process has its own environment variables. You can get those *key-value pairs* by reading `environ` variable, which is declared in `unistd.h` header file as an `extern` `char**` pointer-to-pointer variable.

Environment variables are inherited by *child process* created by the *parent process*. If you use `setenv`/`putenv` functions to create a new *environment variable* in your program, this new variable will only be granted in your *parent* and nested *child processes* until they exit or terminate. If you would like to make these variables permanent, you will need to set them in a startup **shell script**.

In Linux systems, *bash* runs the following script files before it shows up:

- /etc/profile
- /etc/bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile

If you embed your environment variables as `export key=value` commands in the shell script, which is going to be started up by *bash* that your main program will run on top, you might access them from your program or *terminal* itself.